# TabView does not working as expected in android

Tags: android, tabview

I have a tabView in android which is created as follows :

```
            Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost.newTabSpec("Android");
        tabSpecAndroid.setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config));
        tabSpecAndroid.setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost.newTabSpec("Apple");
        tabSpecApple.setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_apple_config));
        tabSpecApple.setContent(intentApple);
```

AppleActivity.class is as defined :

```
public class AppleActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apple_layout);

        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.apple_textView);
        textview.setText("This is Apple tab");

    }
}
```

But I clicked in tab named "Apple" the String "This is Apple tab" in the TextView is not shown . What is wrong here ? Please help me with a solution . The picture is as follows :

[image]

But I when I clicked the others tab such as "Android" the picture is as follows :

[image]

Why the textView in android tab is working wee and why not in Apple tab ?

The alyout for AppleLayout.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/listView1">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
      android:text="TextView"
      android:id="@+id/apple_textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout code for the apple activity

Comment: post your layout.apple_layout.xml

Comment: The code of apple_layout.xml is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add android:orientation="vertical" to LinearLayout. It looks that default is horizontal so your text is at right but not visible because list matches parent.
Or just try put textview above listview to see if it will be visible